# type error in EF 4.1

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have created an entity and it has a key of type Int. when I run the project and use this entity I get following error:

> The 'Id' property on 'Product' could
>   not be set to a 'Int64' value. You
>   must set this property to a non-null
>   value of type 'Int32'.

How can I fix it ?

Edit:

I am using SQL server and entity framework 4.1. I get error in controller action:

```
public ActionResult Test(long id) 
{ 
    return View(repository.GetObligor(id)); 
}
```

Comment: And how do you use the entity? What type is used in your database? You should provide more details.

Comment: Posting your code where the error occurs would be particularly helpful.

Comment: I am using SQL server and entity framework 4.1. I get error in controller action:  public ActionResult Test(long id) {
           return View(repository.GetObligor(id));
        }

Comment: Next time modify your quetion instead of posting code to comment.

Comment: We need to see the definitions of `Product` and `GetObligor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you defined entity with `int` Id but you are passing `long` Id. Try to convert it first to `int` or change Id in entity to `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Just set 'Id' property of 'Product' table as BigInt or in alternate while fetching it from DB just convert this into BigInt as `Convert(BigInt, Id)`